# Spring social login using google plus?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring social. In login.jsp I have below code for `facebook` and `twitter`.

```jsp
<form id="tw_signin" action="<c:url value="/signin/twitter"/>" method="POST">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.forms.tw_signin.submit();">
        <img alt="Twitter" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icons/twitter-login.png">
    </a>
</form>

<form id="facebook_signin" action="<c:url value="/signin/facebook"/>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.forms.facebook_signin.submit();">
        <img alt="Facebook" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icons/facebook-login.png"/>
    </a>
</form>
```

For FB I am calling `document.forms.facebook_signin.submit();`. Similarly what is the config that I need to provide login through `Google+` ?